# How to implement or use a WebSocket in perl?

Tags: perl, websocket, thread-safety, nonblocking

I need to have 3 major things from perl and don't know how to go about it.

- Non Blocking websocket implementation like [`mojo`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo).
- The server needs to accept broadcast calls after it has started
- The server needs to be able to access data that is on a different thread.

I have tried `mojo` but didn't find a way to control the port (I can live with that) and didn't figure out how to call events after the server has started. I wasn't able to test if it could handle events after the fact.

I have tried [`Net::WebSocket::Server`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net%3a%3aWebSocket%3a%3aServer) but it is blocking. I am tempted to wrap my own code around it so that it can handle non blocking and shared data as it is by far the simplest implementation and easy to modify.

I have also tried [`pocket.io`](https://metacpan.org/pod/PocketIO) but it didn't have a very easy way to implement OO design and still remain thread safe. (Mostly because of the [`Plack`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Plack) framework).

Does anyone have a good example of how to do this with [`Mojolicious`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious) or `pocket.io`? If not I will just have to implement my own implementation.

Comment: I would take a longer look at Mojolicious and [this](https://github.com/kraih/mojo/wiki/Writing-websocket-chat-using-Mojolicious-Lite) and [this](https://github.com/xantus/mojo-websocket-examples) example. Mojo does all that you are asking for, but it is spread out in the docs.